# How can we pop-up picture boxes in c# forms like bing images search do

Tags: c#, mouseevent, picturebox, mousehover

I am trying to make my dynamic generated picture boxes acts on a mouse hover like the "bing" do. Below is the picture attached of what bing search looks like on mouse hover :

[image: Bing image search mouse hover]

Now this is my search results of a project I am working on, what i really want to do is that I want to make picture pop-up as the way which is shown above in bing search.

[image: my project results]

**Please note that all of the picture boxes are generated dynamically on the run time.**

Comment: Make use of the mouse over events and create a control to popup and display the enlarged version

Comment: @horHAY i am really new to this thing. i do know that mouse over even exists in it. But i do not know how to use it.

Comment: Did you google "Picture Box Mouse Over" or even "... Pop up" ?

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht ofcourse i do. but didnt find solution relevant to what i am looking for.

Comment: What is the control in which you display those images in your window? Is some grid, list? Or you just put the pictureboxes next to each other manually?

Comment: @PrzemysławŁadyński i generate picture boxes on the run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using picture boxes.
then you can enhance the current picture box like this 
and use it.

```
  //extending the picture box
    public  class PicControl : PictureBox
        {
            // variables to save the picture box old position
            private int _OldWidth;
            private int _OldHeight;
            private int _OldTop;
            private int _OldLeft;
            public PicControl()
            {
            }
    protected override void OnLoadCompleted(System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            _OldTop = this.Top;
            _OldLeft = this.Left;
            _OldWidth = this.Width;
            _OldHeight = this.Height;
            base.OnLoadCompleted(e);
        }
            protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
          {
                 //once mouse enters 
                  // take the backup of height width top left
                 //so we can restore once mouse leaves
                _OldTop = this.Top;
                _OldLeft = this.Left;
                _OldWidth = this.Width;
                _OldHeight = this.Height;
                //decrease the control top left to show hover effect
                this.Top = this.Top - 10;
                this.Left = this.Left - 10;
                // same increase the height width
                this.Height = this.Height + 20;
                this.Width = this.Width + 20;
                 // show to control on top of all
                 this.BringToFront();
                //trigger the base event
                base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            }
            protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
            {
                   // mouse leaves now we have to restore 
                  //picture box to its original position
                this.Height = _OldHeight;
                this.Width = _OldWidth;
                this.Left = _OldLeft;
                this.Top = _OldTop;
                base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            }
        }
```

Now when you add this class in your project and build it,it will
show you PicControl in your toolbox you can replace pictureBox with PicContorl
in order get that effect.
hope it will helps you.
[image: when mouse hover a box]
[image]

Comment: So will it work for every box ? which is generated on the run time ?

Comment: yes, every box should be the picControl. even you generate on runtime

Comment: Pictures pop-ups but i am having an error. Some pictures just disappear after poping up.

Comment: you can see when i hover (fast hovering) over pictures they disappears. on slow hover they dont. please find the result in the link [link](http://s24.postimg.org/6xs5clu05/Untitled.png)

Comment: updated again added
// show to control on top of all
                 this.BringToFront();
in order to show the hover correctly. it should perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example how you could make very trivial popup for such images.

```
    //Sample object representing one of your pictures
    PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
    List<PictureBox> images = new List<PictureBox>();
    images.Add(pb1);

    int frameSize = 5;
    PictureBox popup = new PictureBox();
    popup.Visible = false;
    popup.MouseLeave += (s, a) =>
    {
        popup.Visible = false;
    };

    foreach (var pb in images)
    {
        pb.MouseEnter += (s, a) =>
        {
            var sender = (PictureBox)s;
            popup.Image = sender.Image;
            popup.Left = sender.Left - frameSize;
            popup.Top = sender.Top - frameSize;
            popup.Width = sender.Width + (2 * frameSize);
            popup.Height = sender.Height + (2 * frameSize);
            popup.Visible = true;
            popup.BringToFront();
        };
    }
```

Let's assume your picture boxes are in "images" collection. We have one more picture box which is hidden that will work as popup.

Next for each of them we bind to MouseEnter event. On MouseEnter we position popup picturebox above the hovered image and we set there same image but we make it slightly bigger and centered over underlying picture and we show the popup.

We are also bound to MouseLeave event of popup so when mouse leaves the popup it will dissapear.

Of course it's just a concept to inspire you for further development. Remember to mark as answer if helps you and you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in style sheet

```
.image:hover {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.2); transform:scale(1.2);
}
.image {
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease; transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

and pass this `class` to the image

```
 <img alt="" src="../Sample%20Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg" 
            style="width: 301px; height: 196px" class="image " />
```

input:-
[image: Input image]

Output:-

[image: Output image]

Comment: I do not think this can be used in C#.

Comment: i just googled and found that style sheets can be generated in c# and amazed. thank you for you help. now before using you code i am going to find out how to do style sheets and all this. 
(if you can give me a sample program that would be great)

Comment: I also want to tell you i am not working on a web application. I am working on windows form application ( not written in asp.net)